# Tableau percentage calculating

Tags: tableau-api

I'm quite new in tableau environment.
I have one column with reps. Second column contains values 'Yes' and 'No'. Third with customers names.

I want to count this: 'Yes' Clients/ All clients for each rep

I created calculating field: `COUNT(IF [C2]='Yes' THEN [C2] ELSE NULL END]/COUNT [C2]`

but it doesn't work, to each rep I have a 1 value. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Its hard to diagnose without some sample data, but try changing your denominator to Count(1) to be sure you are counting every row.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently Tableau counts NULLs as well. Try this instead:

```
SUM(IF [C2]='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT([C2])
```

This way you count only the 'Yes'

Comment: I don't think Tableau count's nulls. The whole purpose of the COUNT() function is to count how many rows have a non-null value in the specified column.

Comment: I believe you are right. It is hard to guess given op provided a code with syntax problems. Just wanted to jump in and make him use SUM instead of COUNT, because it is better

Comment: A lot of people don't understand what COUNT() really does, so are less likely to make a mistaken assumption with SUM(). But COUNT() can be more efficient. A database can sometimes compute COUNT() from the index without even fetching blocks of data rows into memory from disk. So I personally think its better to learn to use COUNT() correctly than to just always use SUM(). IMHO